# Convert SQL subqueries into a join

Tags: sql

I have the following (fully functional) `select` which is using multiple subqueries, and I want to switch to joins instead.

```sql
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
WHERE c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active' AND CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) IN (
    SELECT w.WorkerCostCenterCd
    FROM vw_dimworker w
    WHERE w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L') AND w.WorkerKey = (
        SELECT o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey 
        FROM vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o
        WHERE LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
             AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
    )
)
```

I tried writing it like so, but when I run this I get no results, so clearly I bungled it.  What have I done wrong here?

```sql
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w ON w.WorkerCostCenterCd = CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10))
INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd
WHERE w.WorkerKey = o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey
    AND w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L')
    AND c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active' 
    AND LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
    AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data currently looks like and what the expected result should look like? Also, are you using hierarchys?

Comment: Not really, as it's internal data.  But basically the SuperGroupNm is just a string, and the CostCenterNbr is a numeric value.  There's only one result returned, so for example I could get back Scott 17

Comment: I meant sample data. Let me take a look and see what I can make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
INNER JOIN vw_dimworker w
    ON CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) = w.WorkerCostCenterCd
    AND c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active' 
    AND w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L') 
INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o
    ON LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
    AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
    AND o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey = w.WorkerKey
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase your SQL query like below.

```
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
INNER JOIN vw_dimworker W ON w.WorkerCostCenterCd = CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) AND w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L')
WHERE 
    w.WorkerKey = (
        SELECT o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey 
        FROM vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o
        WHERE LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
             AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
    )
)
```

or inner join with vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy

```
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
INNER JOIN vw_dimworker W ON w.WorkerCostCenterCd = CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) AND w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L')
INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy O ON W.WorkerKey = O.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey AND 
    LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
    AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below to increase the readability:

```
SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
FROM vw_dimCostCenter c
INNER JOIN vw_dimworker w on CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) = w.WorkerCostCenterCd 
       and w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L')
INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o on w.WorkerKey = o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey
       and LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
       and o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
WHERE c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply move the subselect  in JOIN (  subelect  ) and apply you in condice to the ON clause eg:

```
  SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
  FROM vw_dimCostCenter c 
  INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT w.WorkerCostCenterCd
      FROM vw_dimworker w
      WHERE w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L') AND w.WorkerKey = (
          SELECT o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey 
          FROM vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o
          WHERE LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
               AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
    ) T ON CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) = T.WorkerCostCenterCd 
                  and  c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active'
```

or  deeeper

```
  SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
  FROM vw_dimCostCenter c 
  INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT w.WorkerCostCenterCd
      FROM vw_dimworker w
      INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o ON  w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L') 
          AND w.WorkerKey = o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey 
            AND LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
               AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
    ) T ON CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) = T.WorkerCostCenterCd and  c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active'
```

or more  deeeper

```
  SELECT c.SuperGroupNm, c.CostCenterNbr
  FROM vw_dimCostCenter c 
  INNER JOIN vw_dimworker w on CAST(c.CostCenterNbr AS VARCHAR(10)) = T.WorkerCostCenterCd 
      and  c.CostCenterStatusTxt = 'Active' 
  INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o ON  w.WorkerStatusCd IN ('A', 'L') 
      AND w.WorkerKey = o.OrganizationHierarchyManagerWorkerKey 
        AND LOWER(o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm) = LOWER('XYZ')
           AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitTreeLevelNbr = 4
```